# How to parse Unicode java applications Vdurmont emoji-java2.0.1 library

Tags: java, jar, emoji

I'm using netbeans IDE for developing **java desktop application** with Vdurmont emoji-java2.0.1 Emoji library. Its working with my netbeans IDE development and sent emojis unicode another side its working fine (Showing fine and correct emoji with emotions). **Problem:** When i clean build and make a .jar with all necessary lib, 
                it showing this **(ðŸ˜¡ and ?)** on another side web app  [Vdurmont emoji-java2.0.1](https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java) library didn't load or not working with myemojiapp.jar file. *please let me know if any need for this ?..

```
            Object finalmsz = "";
            msz = jtp.getText();
            MyHtml2Text parser = new MyHtml2Text();
            try {
                parser.parse(new StringReader(msz));
            } catch (IOException ee) {
                //handle exception my exp
            }
```

### finalmsz = Imoji.parseToUnicode(parser.getText() + str);**

```
            public static String parseToUnicode(String input) {
                String result = input;
                for (Emoji emoji : EmojiManager.getAll()) {
                result = result.replace(emoji.getHtmlHexidecimal(),emoji.getUnicode());
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Please note this parsing not working with my myemojiapp.jar file (showing this ðŸ˜¡ and ?)
but it works fine on my netbeans during development.**

Comment: Hi, I didn't really get what the problem was but first of all, try to update the library to its current version (3.0.1). Can you explain the problem in more details?

Comment: Yes, no issue with current version (3.0.1) and 2.0.1. myemojiapp.jar file (showing this ðŸ˜¡ and ?) IT Works fine with my netbeans IDE.

Comment: When i doing current time development myemojiapp project on my netbeans IDE  Vdurmont emoji-java2.0.1 works fine and showing emoji on chat. But Its create problem with  myemojiapp.jar (showing this ðŸ˜¡ and ?)

Comment: Run myemojiapp.jar file emoji (showing ðŸ˜¡ and ?)